# Jasper .docx export new line height too small

Tags: jasper-reports

I use Jasper to export some Lists to a word document (docx). This works completely fine, but when I try to add a new line the new line is only a few pixels high, at most, so any text in this line will be unreadable. This is a problem because I sometimes need to adjust some of the text and new lines may be necessary.

Here's my .jrxml (left out the irrelevant parts)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="certificate" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1b93a61f-7160-4777-a000-60fff794041b">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="152" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="bb1289d7-18dd-4447-a534-cf612050abc8" positionType="Float" x="0" y="38" width="514" height="38" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <subreportParameter name="textModulesHeader">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{textModules})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["textModules.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

This is what it looks like when I add a new line and enter some text [image]

Is there any way to fix this weird behaviour of jasper or is there any alternative that I ca n use?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding this property :

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.docx.flexible.row.height" value="true"/>
```